# Kotlin equivalent of Java's equalsIgnoreCase

Tags: android, kotlin

What is the equivalent of Java `equalsIgnoreCase` in Kotlin to compare `String` values?

I have used `equals` but it's not case insensitive.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/equals.html#parameters

Answer (score 270, accepted):

You can use `equals` but specify `ignoreCase` parameter:

```
"example".equals("EXAMPLE", ignoreCase = true)
```

Answer (score 11):

As per the Kotlin Documentation :

```
fun String?.equals(
    other: String?, 
    ignoreCase: Boolean = false
): Boolean
```

> https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/equals.html

For Example:

> ```
> val name: String = "Hitesh"
> when{
> name.equals("HITESH", true) -> {
>                                 // DO SOMETHING
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 5):

@hluhovskyi's answer is correct, however to use it on `EditText` or `TextView`, use following -

```
etPassword.text.toString().equals(etConfirmPassword.text.toString(), ignoreCase = true)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case,

```
string1.contains(string2, ignoreCase = true)
```

This worked for me.
Becase I'm using like a search function here.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you don't need to find alternatives since Kotlin reuses existing Java types like `String`. Actually, these types are mapped to Kotlin internal types. In the case of `String` it looks like this:

`java.lang.String` ->   `kotlin.String`

Therefore, the desired method `equalsIgnoreCase` would only be available if it was also provided in `kotlin.String`, which isn’t. The Kotlin designers decided to provide a more generic [`equals`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/equals.html#parameters) function that let's you specify the case insensitivity with a boolean parameter.

You can use the Java `String` class at any time if that's really necessary (it's not recommended, IntelliJ will complain about this):

```
("hello" as java.lang.String).equalsIgnoreCase("Hello")
```

With the help of an extension function, we could even add the functionality to the `kotlin.String` class:

```
fun String.equalsIgnoreCase(other: String) = 
    (this as java.lang.String).equalsIgnoreCase(other)
```

Comment: Kotlin has equalIgnoreCase function implemented, but with a little change with its own way i.e. "str1".equal("Str1", true) for ignore case and "str1".equal("Str1", false) for match case. Second argument is optional you can skip it. By default it is false and apply on match case

Answer (score 1):

You could make an extension method:

```
    /**
     * Shortcut to compare strings while ignoring case
     */
    fun String.similarTo(aString: String): Boolean {
        return equals(aString,true)
    }
```

Usage:

```
   val upperCase = "ϴẞ"
   val lowerCase = "θß"

   if (upperCase.similarTo(lowerCase)) {
      // Do your thing…
   }
```